# Built in commands fail when used in for loop

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

I have a portion of a script that is intended to remove the ":" out of the time and "/" out of the date as returned by time /t and date /t commands. If I execute the command in a command prompt (cmd.exe), the expected values are returned:

> C:\Windows\system32>time /t
>   02:49 PM
>   C:\Windows\system32>date /t
>   Tue 07/03/2018

If I place the same commands at the beginning of my batch script, I get the results I expect. However, if I place the same command within a for statement to parse out the ":" and "/". I receive the following messages:

> 'date /t' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   'time /t' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Running the for command outside of the batch file works fine. I have recreated the batchfile from scratch to be sure there were no random odd characters present.

Here is the script itself:

```
time /t
date /t

for /F "Tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') Do Set _cdate=%%c%%a%%b
for /F "Tokens=1,2,3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /t') Do Set _ctime=%%a%%b%%c
pause
```

This same script works fine on another server as well as my desktop. I am at a loss as to what makes this new server different. (Aside from one is 32bit) The COMSPEC is correct. (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe) These commands are part of a larger script to provide file name prefix for logging.

Comment: date /t and time /t commands output is locale/user settings dependent. Either use `wmic os get LocalDateTime` or `powershell -nop -c "get-date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS'"`to get a date time string in the desired format. To put the output into a variable you'll need to wrap it in a for /f command. There are lots of examples her in [SO]

Comment: The script using the "date /t" and "time /t" command works fine on another Windows 2008 server as it is coded in my test above. I am trying to discern what makes this new server fail. This same script is used across several Windows 2008 R2 servers without issue, just this one server fails when using the commands within a for loop.

Comment: My first thought was that extensions were explicitly disabled but that throws a completely different error.

Comment: If you insist on using quite old techniques and proved to be error prone due to facts you usually can't control that is your good right - the ways I suggested are used by a lot of admins for good reasons.

Comment: @Squashman, not sure about `date /T` and `time /T`, but `for /F` is not going to work without command extensions...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes that was kind of my point.  I wasn't sure what error disabling extensions would throw when using a `FOR /F`.  `/F was unexpected at this time.`.  I just tested disabling extensions and just ran the `DATE /T` on its own line.  It totally screws up that command.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this batch script using **WMIC** to get Date and Time not depending for locale/user settings :

```dos
@echo off
Title Get Date and Time using WMIC
Call :Get_Date_Time 
echo Date : %Year%-%Month%-%day%
echo Time : %Hour%:%Min%:%Sec%
Pause>nul & Exit
::********************************************************************************************
:Get_Date_Time
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "Year=%MyDate:~0,4%"
set "Month=%MyDate:~4,2%"
set "Day=%MyDate:~6,2%"
set "Hour=%MyDate:~8,2%"
set "Min=%MyDate:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%MyDate:~12,2%
exit /b
::********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I attempted to use the WMIC method and found that it takes longer to return the date and time that using the time /t and date /t method. In my testing, I noted it took up to about 5 seconds to return the date time in the desired format. Is there a faster way with WMIC? Compared to less than a second with the "old school" method. I will look at this further.

Comment: @gritts the good thing about use WMIC is that it will always output in the same format.  The DATE and TIME commands as well as the DATE and TIME system variables are region and computer specific.  If my system settings are different then yours, your code would not run correctly on my computer.  WMIC does not have this problem. You could try capturing the date and time with Powershell as well but it still will not be as fast as native cmd.exe.